# Is there a way to use shiny download buttons to download (non-imported/manipulated) data from the app?

Tags: r, shiny-reactivity

I've seen a lot of documentation in Hadley's shiny draft book about being able to download csvs of existing databses, or data that is input into the app, but what about data that has been manipulated on the back-end of the app? For example if you have a list of numeric inputs, you press a button, and they all get multiplied by 50, how do you export the new list of imported data * 50? Is this possible with the download button interactivity?

Comment: Sure. Make a new data frame with the new values, perhaps as a `reactive` value. In the `downloadHandler` `content` function, save the data frame in the format you want (CSV, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As Kent mentioned in the comment this is very possible. Below is a simple app that would allow you to multiply all fields in `mtcars` by an arbitrary number and download the file:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("val", "Value", 1),
  downloadButton("file", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output, sesssion) {
  tbl <- reactive(mtcars * input$val)
  output$file <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "example.csv",
    content = function(x) {
      write.csv(tbl(), x)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```